# Microsoft Word 2013 - Hyperlink issues with figure captions inside text boxes

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, caption

In my document I created a list of figures. When I add captions to the figures, some of them are "captioned" with plain text and in some images (mostly those that are through text) the caption is added inside a text box.

Those captions that are inside text boxes have the following issue. In the list of figures, the hyperlink points to the file location. If I send the file to another location, then the issue is fixed by simply refreshing the list of figures. The problem persists though when I save the file as pdf. In the list of figures, when I hover over the image, a hyperlink that points to the location where the original .docx file was saved before making the conversion appears.

After thorough search I found another person who had the same issue:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/difference-in-table-of-contents-hyperlinks-to/d347680f-f9be-41f6-b018-44f08248932e?db=5&page=2&auth=1

The workaround he was proposed (add the picture and the caption inside a table) is infeasible in my case because many of those pictures are through text. I also tried to convert the text boxes to frames but the problem persists. Any ideas ?

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: One possibility might be to insert a nested TC field (they are invisible) close to each figure, but in the normal text stream (i.e. not in a text box). The field code could be, e.g. { TC "Figure: { SEQ Figurex }" \f F }, and the associated TOC would be something like { TOC \h \f F }. (All the { } need to be the special field brace pairs you can insert using ctrl-F9 in Windows Word, and you would need to select all these TCs and update them before updating your table of Figures.

Comment: Your proposal gave me an idea that worked. I noticed that the field code of the captions inside the textboxes contains the link to the file which is totally unneccessary. I removed the link and left the field code identical to this of the other captions and the problem was solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should post the fix as an answer instead of adding it to your question

Comment: Agreed with @RohitGupta. You should not edit your question to say “FIXED” and you should not edit your question to add the answer. The reality is if it is indeed fixed, just post it as an answer. But given this question is nearly 8 years old I don’t even know if the original poster will see this.

Comment: Although archaic, I fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a different method without hacking around in office's XML code, which is not accessible to most users.

First of all, I would use grouping of the image and the to-be-attached (and unwanted) text box.

Secondly, when I set a reference from inside my text to the image and click on it, then I await to jump to the top edge of the linked image, and not to the labeling text below the image. So I would just not use Word's badly-programmed referencing category called 'FIGURES'. Instead I create my own category for figures. And then set the link to the image, and not under the image. The disadvantage: This does not let me update the numbering of the figures, when I move them around. Another referencing category could be bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

To those who face the same issue, an easy (though "manual") solution is to edit the field code of each entry on the list of figures that is made of captions inside the textboxes and remove the link part:

The entry of the caption looks like this:

{HYPERLINK "file:///C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.docx" \l "_Toc437184080"}
I changed it to this:

{HYPERLINK \l "_Toc437184080"}
And It works correctly.